# catch the serial number from bootloader

Tags: linux, arm, bootloader, busybox, u-boot

I want to catch the serial number which has been written into the U-Boot environment.

Bootloader :U-boot 1.2
kernel:2.6.24
tool-chain:arm-linux-gcc-3.4.1
rfs :busybox-1.9.2

```
Creating 3 MTD partitions on "NAND 64MiB 3,3V 8-bit":
0x00000000-0x00060000 : "bootloader"
0x00060000-0x00260000 : "kernel"
0x00260000-0x03e60000 : "rootfilesystem"
```

Please tell me how can I do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What serial number? All I see is 3 mtd partitions with their memory locations...

Comment: This is a configuration question, no programming required.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass it on the kernel command-line, and then read it from inside linux using `/proc/cmdline`

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the kernel boot arguments and /proc/cmdline to pass this kind of stuff to Linux: 
http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/LinuxKernelArgs

However you could also check out the command line tools for reading/writing UBoot environment here:
http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/HowCanIAccessUBootEnvironmentVariablesInLinux

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can get to the u-boot command line, you can look at the environment variables - dump them out with printenv.  Our system has one called "unlock_env" - if your system has this value you can just enter "echo $unlock_env" and it will show you the contents.  The address of the environment sector will be the first hex value.

While you are in u-boot, "echo $serial#" should print the serial number, but I assume you want to read it after you've booted into the O/S.

Anyway, once you have the address of the environment sector, you have to parse the data in the sector and look for "serial#".  Shouldn't be that hard, I think it's probably just a series of NULL-terminated strings.  Good luck.